# Identify the module/control in DNN v4.9

Tags: dotnetnuke

I have a client whose DNN site suddenly stopped working. All they know is that some passwords where changed. My challenge is to locate the module or control that drives a particular page e.g:

`/testing/tabId/100/default.aspx`

Obviously, there is no physical file or folder in the path (which I expected), but I need to locate the source that is generating the markup for that URL so I can adjust some settings and get everything working again.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start by digging in to the database, looking at the TabModules table, look at all ModuleIds that are on the page (Tabid 100)

From there you can track the modules table to the DesktopModules table to figure out which Module is the one being loaded. The ModuleDefinitions table will have the ASCX path that is being loaded.